# Finding partial fractions of $\frac{z^3+2z^2-2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2}$ and/or using Cauchy's formula to solve

Tags: inverse, transformation, partial-fractions, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to find the inverse z-transform of

\begin{equation}
x(z)=\frac{z^3+2z^2-2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}
\end{equation}

and for this we need to get partial fractions.  I have tried multiple approaches, the first

$z^3+2z^2-2z:z^3-2z^2+2z-4=1+\frac{4z^2-4z-4}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}$
which can be further separated as:

$1+4\frac{z^2(z-1)}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}-\frac{4}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}$

But here , nothing cancels out, so with those denominators, nothing can be made out for an inverse z-transform.

Then I tried

\begin{equation}
\frac{z^3+2z^2-2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}=\frac{z(z^2+2z-2)}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{z(z^2+2z-2)}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}=\frac{z^2(z+2)}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}-\frac{2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}
\end{equation}

But here also, no part of the function can be simplified further.

I was tempted to use Cauchy integral formula on for higher order functions, on

\begin{equation}
x(z)=\frac{z^3+2z^2-2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2)}
\end{equation}

but can that be done?

Thanks

UPDATE;

taking the partial fractions from the decomposition:

$1+\frac{2}{z-2}+\frac{2z}{(z^2+2)}$, we get the inverse z.transform by the table:

Inverse z-transform of 1:

$1=\delta_n $ for $  \{\delta_0=1, \ \ \delta_{n\ne0}=0, \}$

$\frac{2}{z-2}$ For this, I couldn't find a inverse z-transform from the table, however I did a calculation of it using Cauchy's theorem

$\frac{2}{z-2}\rightarrow Res(2)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 2}\frac{2z^{n-1}}{z-2}=\frac{(z-2)2z^{n-1}}{z-2}=2^n$

Same for the third term, I couldn't find an inverse z-transform from the table, hence:

$\frac{2z}{(z^2+2)}\rightarrow Res(\sqrt{2}i)=\lim_{z\rightarrow \sqrt{2}i}\frac{2zz^{n-1}}{(z^2+2)}=\frac{2z}{(z+2i)}=\frac{2(\sqrt{2}i)^n}{(2\sqrt{2}i)}=(
i)^{n-1}$

and the second pole:

$\frac{2z}{(z^2+2)}\rightarrow Res(-\sqrt{2}i)=\lim_{z\rightarrow -\sqrt{2}i}\frac{2zz^{n-1}}{(z^2+2)}=\frac{2z}{(z-2i)}=\frac{2(-\sqrt{2}i)^n}{(-2\sqrt{2}i)}= (-1)^n(i)^{n-1}$

but this last transform is not correct according to WA

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Z-transform+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%222z%2F%28z%5E2%2B2%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22n%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22ZTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22z%22

Comment: Any calculus book gives an algorithm to find the partial-fractions decomposition for _any_ rational function.

Comment: That is not true. A rational function such as $\frac{z}{z^4+z+1}$ has not partial fraction. At least, there are several rational functions that have no partial fraction counterpart. Read here https://www.quora.com/Are-only-proper-rational-fractions-converted-into-partial-fractions

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This downgrading the question is evidently evidence of bad judgement. It is wider than you think, it is made for solving the Cauchy integral of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint x(z)z^{n-1}dz$. The partial fraction was just one path.

Comment: $z/(z^4+z+1$ certainly has a partial fraction decomposition. I can't tell you what the coefficients are because I can't factor the denominator - that doesn't say the partial fractions doesn't exist. Regarding that link: In that calculus book it explains that you first use long division to convert an improper fraction to a polynomial plus a proper fraction, then decompose the proper fraction.

Comment: my judgement has nothing to do with it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{z^3+2z^2-2z}{(z-2)(z^2+2)} = 1 + {2 \over z-2} + {2z \over z^2+2}
$$
You know that the solution is of the form
$$
a + {b \over z-2} + {cz+d \over z^2+2}
$$
Reduce to the same denominator, identify with your initial fraction, deduce linear relations between a,b,c,d, solve.

You can be a bit faster, e.g. by noticing that a is the limit of the fraction when $z$ goes to infinity, and thus should be 1. Also you can get $b$ by multiplying the fraction by $z-2$ and letting $z$ goes to 2.

Note also that you can use a CAS such as [maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/) to check your result.

```
(%i1) partfrac((z^3+2*z^2-2*z)/(z-2)/(z^2+2), z);
```

$$1 + {2 \over z-2} + {2z \over z^2+2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Comment: How did you reach  the form $a+\frac{b}{z-2}+....$ ?

Comment: This is what tells you the statement of the partial fraction decomposition theorem. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: sorry, but those examples are from the complexity of this  case!

Comment: No, I wrote that the wikipedia page does not explain this case which is more complex

Comment: The wikipedia page explains pretty well your case. In the statement on the wikipedia page, take $g = (z-2)(z^2+2)$, in other words $p_1 = (z-2)$ and $p_2 = (z^2+2)$ and then the conclusion of the statement gives you the expression in my post.

Comment: but how do you get the three numerators

Comment: The numerators are polynomials whose degree is less than their respective denominators. So if the denominator is of degree one, this is a constant, let us denote it by b, if it is of degree two, this is a degree at most one polynomial, let us denote it by cz+d.

Comment: got it, so I use that structure and ignore whats in the numerator.

Comment: Well, you need to compute the coefficients of the numerators, for example by reducing to the same denominator and identifying with the sought expression.

Comment: finding 1 was no problem, then, it got  worse